# Why do we need polar coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

So, I haven't formally started learning about polar coordinates or anything yet, I'm just curious about them. I'm saying this to convey that I might not understand many technical terms.

So, I want to know how exactly polar coordinates came into existence i.e. what gave rise to the idea of polar coordinates. I would also like to know how they found their purpose/applications later on and some examples of things that they can do but Cartesian coordinates can not.

This is my first question here. Sorry if it's off topic.

Thank you!

Comment: "examples of things that they can do but Cartesian coordinates can not" -- there's nothing that one set of coordinates can do that another can not. There is an inexhaustible list of things that are *easier* in one set of coordinates than another (simpler algebra, simpler calculus, etc.), and picking one versus the other is entirely a matter of convenience. This typically corresponds to symmetry properties of whatever the coordinates are be used to parametrize.

Comment: @jwimberley So, is it that some mathematician thought "hmm, this would be easier if I express the position of the point using it's distance from the origin and the direction" or something like that?

Comment: I don't know the history, but it was surely something like that.

Comment: *"I want to know how exactly polar coordinates came into existence i.e. what gave rise to the idea of polar coordinates."* Then [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) might be the better place for this question.

Comment: @Blue Thanks! I'll post it there but does that mean that it's off topic here?

Comment: @Norman_22194: Math history questions aren't exactly off-topic here (there's a `math-history` tag), but HSM.SE was created to give those types of questions specialized attention. Since people have already provided some insights as to the utility of polar coordinates, you should leave the question here; but in the post to HSM.SE, focus on the "I want to know how they came into existence" part, and leave out the "I would like to know how they found their purpose" part. (You should link the questions to each other for context.)

Comment: @Blue Thank you!

Comment: @Blue: For those interested, this question is now [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12711/264), with some answers, at the History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that comes to mind is for aircraft navigation. The location of a plane in the Earth's atmosphere is described by a height above land ($r$ in polar coordinates) and latitude/longitude which are two angles, $\theta$ and $\phi$. Using $x$, $y$ and $z$ would be needlessly complicated for describing where a plane is.

This is one example of where polar coordinates are beneficial over cartesian. All coordinate systems "do" the same things, but some simplify problems more than others.

Comment: Nice example! But, I don't think it serves as an example for the situations that could have led to the development of the polar coordinates, but a nice example, nonetheless. As I asked for applications as well, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Curvilinear coordinate systems, like polar coordinates, came into being because they simplify computations in certain situations. For example think of a body moving with constant angular velocity $\omega$ around a circle of radius one centered at the origin. Using cartesian coordinates $x, y$ its motion is described by
$$
x = \cos\omega t,\ 
y = \sin\omega t
$$
in polar coordinates $r, \theta$ it becomes much nicer
$$
r = 1,
\theta = \omega t 
$$
this can simplify other computations you might want to do that are related to this kind of motion.

Comment: That's a nice example but I don't understand what type of computations you are referring to. Please provide an example (or examples), if possible.

Comment: a simple example: say you want to know how much time it takes for the body to comple a full cycle, using polar coordinates the answer is trivial to see: $2\pi/\omega$

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinates are useful in differential equations, mainly when solving problems related to variable separable form and sometimes useful in finding out wronskian

Comment: Well, but polar coordinates came before differential equations did, right? While this might be a useful application (I'm not sure, as I don't know what differential equations are), I don't think it serves as an example for the situations that could have led to the development of the polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to this topic, but from my reading, polar coordinates are practically useful in real-world applications where distances and angles are circular or spherical. For example, if there is a spinning motor and an engineer needs to calculate details like what force or speed needs to be applied to produce certain distances or angles, then polar coordinates could make calculations easier in situations where the spinning is restricted to circular (2D) or spherical (3D). Another example I've read is when physicists study the effects of force fields (e.g., magnetic or gravitational fields) whose strengths radiates spherically from a center point and the need is to calculate distances from the center and angles from the center. There again, polar coordinates make calculations easier than Cartesian coordiantes.